# Set TextView instead of toast from fragment in activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, textview, settext, android-toast

I have been developing an app that includes login registration , GPS and QR scanner.
Now I have my QR scan code in the profilefragment.java and I'm calling it from mainactivity.java.The button for QR scan is in the profilefragment.xml and main activity has mainactivity.java which has the try catch block. Instead of going in try-catch block it's showing the toast message. Also the QR generated string format is correct.

Code for QR scan in profile fragment (QR scan result in main activity.java)

```
 public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

private TextView tv_name, tv_email, tv_message;
private SharedPreferences pref;
private AppCompatButton btn_change_password, btn_logout;
private EditText et_old_password, et_new_password;
private AlertDialog dialog;
private ProgressBar progress;
private Button buttonScan, Nextbutton;
private TextView textViewUnique;
private IntentIntegrator qrScan;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);


    initViews(view);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    pref = getActivity().getPreferences(0);
    tv_name.setText("Welcome : " + pref.getString(Constants.NAME, ""));
    tv_email.setText(pref.getString(Constants.EMAIL, ""));

}

private void initViews(View view) {

    tv_name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
    tv_email = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_email);
    btn_change_password = (AppCompatButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_chg_password);
    btn_logout = (AppCompatButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_logout);
    buttonScan = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonScan);
    Nextbutton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.Next);
    textViewUnique = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewUniqueId);
    btn_change_password.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn_logout.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonScan.setOnClickListener(this);
    qrScan = new IntentIntegrator(getActivity());
    Nextbutton.setOnClickListener(this);

}


private void showDialog() {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_change_password, null);
    et_old_password = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.et_old_password);
    et_new_password = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.et_new_password);
    tv_message = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_message);
    progress = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progress);
    builder.setView(view);
    builder.setTitle("Change Password");
    builder.setPositiveButton("Change Password", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();
    dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String old_password = et_old_password.getText().toString();
            String new_password = et_new_password.getText().toString();
            if (!old_password.isEmpty() && !new_password.isEmpty()) {

                progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                changePasswordProcess(pref.getString(Constants.EMAIL, ""), old_password, new_password);

            } else {

                tv_message.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                tv_message.setText("Fields are empty");
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.btn_chg_password:
            showDialog();
            break;
        case R.id.btn_logout:
            logout();
            break;
        case R.id.buttonScan:
            qrScan.initiateScan();
            break;
        case R.id.Next:
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MapMainActivity.class);
            getActivity().startActivity(intent);
            break;
    }
}

private void logout() {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(Constants.IS_LOGGED_IN, false);
    editor.putString(Constants.EMAIL, "");
    editor.putString(Constants.NAME, "");
    editor.putString(Constants.UNIQUE_ID, "");
    editor.apply();
    goToLogin();
}

private void goToLogin() {

    Fragment login = new LoginFragment();
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.fragment_frame, login);
    ft.commit();
}

private void changePasswordProcess(String email, String old_password, String new_password) {

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(Constants.BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    RequestInterface requestInterface = retrofit.create(RequestInterface.class);

    User user = new User();
    user.setEmail(email);
    user.setOld_password(old_password);
    user.setNew_password(new_password);
    ServerRequest request = new ServerRequest();
    request.setOperation(Constants.CHANGE_PASSWORD_OPERATION);
    request.setUser(user);
    Call<ServerResponse> response = requestInterface.operation(request);

    response.enqueue(new Callback<ServerResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ServerResponse> call, retrofit2.Response<ServerResponse> response) {

            ServerResponse resp = response.body();
            if (resp.getResult().equals(Constants.SUCCESS)) {
                progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                tv_message.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                dialog.dismiss();
                Snackbar.make(getView(), resp.getMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } else {
                progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                tv_message.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                tv_message.setText(resp.getMessage());

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ServerResponse> call, Throwable t) {

            Log.d(Constants.TAG, "failed");
            progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            tv_message.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            tv_message.setText(t.getLocalizedMessage());

        }

    });
}
```

}

mainactivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
private TextView textViewUnique;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
 View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile,container,false);
 TextView textViewUnique = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewUniqueId);
//return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container);
 return view;

}
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 textViewUnique = (TextView) findViewById(com.learn2crack.loginregistration.R.id.textViewUniqueId);
 pref = getPreferences(0);
 initFragment();
 }
 private void initFragment() {
 Fragment fragment;
 if (pref.getBoolean(Constants.IS_LOGGED_IN, false)) {
 fragment = new ProfileFragment();
 } else {
   fragment = new LoginFragment();
 }
 FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
 ft.replace(R.id.fragment_frame, fragment);
 ft.commit();
 }
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
 IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
 if (result != null) {
 //if qrcode has nothing in it
 if (result.getContents() == null) {
 Toast.makeText(this, "Result Not Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 } else {
 //if qr contains data
 try {
 ProfileFragment profileFragment = new ProfileFragment();
 profileFragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
 JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(result.getContents());
 textViewUnique.setText(obj.getString("unique_id"));
 //textViewUnique.setText(obj.getString("unique id"));
 } catch (Exception e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
 //if control comes here
 //that means the encoded format not matches
 //in this case you can display whatever data is available on the qrcode
 //to a toast
 Toast.makeText(this, result.getContents(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }
 }
 } else {
 super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
 }
 }
 }
```

The two XML are

activitymain.xml

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 tools:context="com.learn2crack.loginregistration.MainActivity">
 <FrameLayout
 android:id="@+id/fragment_frame"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
 </LinearLayout>
 </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

profile fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/activity_main"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
 android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
 android:gravity="center"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:baselineAligned="false">

 <Button
 android:id="@+id/buttonScan"
 android:layout_width="104dp"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:text="QR Scan"
 android:layout_gravity="right" />
 <TextView
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:text="unique_id"
 android:textSize="20dp" />
 <TextView
 android:id="@+id/textViewUniqueId"
 android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
 android:textSize="20sp"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that Your Fragment is replaced in your `MainActivity`'s container that is `fragment_frame` in your code.
Two steps that we are going to follow - 
**1) Create public method to your `activity` i.e `MainActivity` in your case**

```
public void setRequiredText(String text) {
    if(textViewUnique != null) {
        textViewUnique.setText(text);
    }
}
```

**2) Call `MainActivity`'s method from your `Fragment` to update `TextView`**

```
Activity act = getActivity(); // Get activity to which your fragment is attached
if (act instanceof MainActivity) {
    ((MainActivity) act).setRequiredText(obj.getString("unique_id"))
}
```

And you're done.